# Single Column rpm command output

Tags: ruby, linux, terminal

I have an application where I want to get the RPM info of several packages and format it in a pleasing and eye-catching way. *boom*.

My problem is that `rpm` wants to format the data into two columns, which is annoying.

**Command**

```
rpm -qi ruby
```

**Result**

```
Name        : ruby                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.8.6.36                          Vendor: (none)
Release     : 2                             Build Date: Thu 18 Sep 2008 10:50:30 AM EDT
Install Date: Thu 25 Sep 2008 12:12:53 PM EDT      Build Host: kickbench
Group       : Development/Languages         Source RPM: ruby-1.8.6.36-2.src.rpm
Size        : 1664035                          License: Ruby License/GPL - see COPYING
Signature   : (none)
URL         : http://www.ruby-lang.org/
Summary     : An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language.
Description : [truncated]
```

**What I want**

```
Name        : ruby
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.8.6.36
Vendor      : (none)
Release     : 2
Build Date  : Thu 18 Sep 2008 10:50:30 AM EDT
Install Date: Thu 25 Sep 2008 12:12:53 PM EDT
Build Host  : kickbench
Group       : Development/Languages
Source RPM  : ruby-1.8.6.36-2.src.rpm
Size        : 1664035
License     : Ruby License/GPL - see COPYING
Signature   : (none)
URL         : http://www.ruby-lang.org/
Summary     : An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language.
Description : [truncated]
```

Is there any way to get this formatting without manually specifying a reaally long `--queryformat`?

Alternatively, any way to do this native to Ruby would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pairs = %x{rpm -qi ruby}
       .split(/(?<!:)\s{2,}(?![\s:])|#$//)
       .map{|line| line.split(/\s*:\s+/, 2)}
width = pairs.map{|pair| pair.first.length}.max
pairs.each{|k, v| puts "#{k.ljust(width)}: #{v}"}
```

Comment: Well. This isn't pretty, but it answers the question. I decided to use the query format.